# Ação ao finalizar o request no angular

Tags: angular

Possuo um loading que é ativado no início da minha requisição e preciso fazer com que ele pare ao finalizar a requisição.

Tentei algo como:

```
  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    this.loading = true;
    this.authenticationService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        },
        error => {throw error},
        () => {this.loading = false}
      )
  }
```

O loading não está parando. Eu lembro que tinha um terceiro parametro do subscribe que ocorre quando o request finaliza, porém não estou conseguindo implementar.

Comment: Se adicionar um `console.log` nesta terceira função, ele será executado?

Comment: parametro complete

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não executa...

Comment: Dependendo de onde vem sua fonte o subscribe não morre, ele fica perpetuando sempre esperando novas atualizações. Exemplo: em um request via API ele te retorna os dados no `next` e então morre em seguida enviando um `complete`, se você assina uma mudança de estado interno da sua aplicação e não dispara um complete por ela, seu subscribe vai estar sempre escutando um `next`, neste caso você poderia encerrar o `loading` dentro do `next`.

Comment: consegui com um operator do rxjs, coloquei a resposta se alguém precisar

Comment: No seu caso, como o `next` está omitido, ele está sendo processado quando você recebe seu objeto `data`, só esclarecendo.

Comment: @Leonardo obrigado pelos esclarecimentos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui através do operador **finalize** do rxjs:

```
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

No final minha função ficou dessa forma:

```
  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.registrarForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    this.loading = true
    this.authenticationService.registrar(this.registrarForm.value)
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => this.loading = false)
      )
      .subscribe((res) => {
        if(res !== ""){ //Cadastrou com sucesso então pode pegar token e encaminhar para tela de login
          this.getTokenAdministrador()
        }
      }
    )
  }
```